# graphviz collapse parallel paths

Tags: graphviz

Is it possible to collapse multiple paths like shown in the picture with graphviz? And if so any suggestions on how this could be achieved?

[image]

Comment: Bot quite sure what you are asking.  Is it how to get B1->A and B2->A to terminate in the same place?  Or am I off in the weeds again?

Comment: I now see that it's not really clear what I'm asking. So I will try and rephrase: how can I create the 3 dots? So assuming I have a graph like in the picture but were all the nodes from B1 to B99 are drawn how would I change that graph into a graph like that in the picture were B4 to B98 is not showed, but replaced by the 3 dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm used to the weeds.
Comment out unwanted nodes and edges and add 3 nodes with **shape=point**.  You might also create invisible edges to/from the new nodes, I did not.
This:

```
digraph ellipsis {
 rankdir=RL
 nodesep=.1
 node [shape=circle]
 {
   rank=same
   B1
   B2 
   B3 
   /* comment out unwanted nodes
   B4
   B5
   ...
   */
   e4  [shape=point]
   e5  [shape=point]
   e6  [shape=point]
   B99
   edge [style=invis]
   B1 ->  B2 ->  B3  -> e4 ->  e5 -> e6 ->  B99
 }
 C -> B1
 C -> B2 
 C -> B3 
 /* comment out unwanted edges
 C -> B4
 */
 C -> B99

 B1  -> A
 B2  -> A
 B3  -> A
 /* comment out more unwanted edges
 B4 -> A
 */
 B99 -> A
}
```

Produces this:
[image]